# Relationships created by a rake task are not persisted though the rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, neo4j

I'm working my first project using Neo4j. I'm parsing wikipedia's page and pagelinks dumps to create a graph where the nodes are pages and the edges are links. 
I've defined some rake tasks that download the dumps, parse the data, and save it in a Neo4j database. At the end of the rake task I print the number of pages and links created, and some of the pages with the most links. Here is the output of the raks task for the [zawiki](https://za.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yiebdaeuz).

```
$ rake wiki[zawiki]
[ omitted ] 
...
:: Done parsing zawiki
:: 1984 pages
:: 2144 links
:: The pages with the most links are:
9625.0 - Emijrp/List_of_Wikipedians_by_number_of_edits_(bots_included): 40
1363.0 - Gvangjsih_Bouxcuengh_Swcigih: 30
9112.0 - Fuzsuih: 27
1367.0 - Cungzcoj: 26
9279.0 - Vangz_Yenfanh: 19
```

It looks like pages and links are being created, but when I start a rails console, or the server the links aren't found.

```
$ rails c 
jruby-1.7.5 :013 > Pages.all.count
=> 1984 
jruby-1.7.5 :003 > Pages.all.reduce(0) { |count, page| count + page.links.count}
=> 0 
jruby-1.7.5 :012 > Pages.all.sort_by { |p| p.links.count }.reverse[0...5].map { |p|  p.links.count }
=> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Here is the rake task, and [this is the projects github page](https://github.com/everett1992/wiki_graph). Can anyone tell me why the links aren't saved?

```
DUMP_DIR = Rails.root.join('lib','assets')


desc "Download wiki dumps and parse them"
task :wiki, [:wiki] => 'wiki:all'

namespace :wiki do
  task :all, [:wiki] => [:get, :parse] do |t, args|
    # Print info about the newly created pages and links.
    link_count = 0
    Pages.all.each do |page|
      link_count += page.links.count
    end
    indent "Done parsing #{args[:wiki]}"
    indent "#{Pages.count} pages"
    indent "#{link_count} links"

    indent "The pages with the most links are:"
    Pages.all.sort_by { |a| a.links.count }.reverse[0...5].each do |page|
      puts "#{page.page_id} - #{page.title}: #{page.links.count}"
    end
  end


  desc "Download wiki page and page links database dumps to /lib/assets"
  task :get, :wiki do |t, args|
    indent "Downloading dumps"
    sh "#{Rails.root.join('lib', "get_wiki").to_s} #{args[:wiki]}"
    indent "Done"
  end


  desc "Parse all dumps"
  task :parse, [:wiki] => 'parse:all'

  namespace :parse do
    task :all, [:wiki] => [:pages, :pagelinks]

    desc "Read wiki page dumps from lib/assests into the database"
    task :pages, [:wiki] => :environment do |t, args|
      parse_dumps('page', args[:wiki]) do |obj|
        page = Pages.create_from_dump(obj)
      end
      indent = "Created #{Pages.count} pages"
    end

    desc "Read wiki pagelink dumps from lib/assests into the database"
    task :pagelinks, [:wiki] => :environment do |t, args|
      errors = 0
      parse_dumps('pagelinks', args[:wiki]) do |from_id, namespace, to_title|
        from = Pages.find(:page_id => from_id)
        to = Pages.find(:title => to_title)
        if to.nil? || from.nil?
          errors = errors.succ
        else
          from.links << to
          from.save
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

def indent *args
  print ":: "
  puts args
end

def parse_dumps(dump, wiki_match, &block)
  wiki_match ||= /\w+/
  DUMP_DIR.entries.each do |file|
    file, wiki = *(file.to_s.match(Regexp.new "(#{wiki_match})-#{dump}.sql"))
    if file
      indent "Parsing #{wiki} #{dump.pluralize} from #{file}"
      each_value(DUMP_DIR.join(file), &block)
    end
  end
end

def each_value(filename)
  f = File.open(filename)
  num_read = 0

  begin                               # read file until line starting with INSERT INTO
    line = f.gets
  end until line.match /^INSERT INTO/

  begin
    line = line.match(/\(.*\)[,;]/)[0]  # ignore begining of line until (...) object
    begin
      yield line[1..-3].split(',').map { |e| e.match(/^['"].*['"]$/) ?  e[1..-2] : e.to_f }
      num_read = num_read.succ

      line = f.gets.chomp
    end while(line[0] == '(')          # until next insert block, or end of file
  end while  line.match /^INSERT INTO/ # Until line doesn't start with (...

  f.close
end
```

app/models/pages.rb

```
class Pages < Neo4j::Rails::Model
  include Neo4j::NodeMixin
  has_n(:links).to(Pages)

  property :page_id
  property :namespace,        :type => Fixnum
  property :title,            :type => String
  property :restrictions,     :type => String
  property :counter,          :type => Fixnum
  property :is_redirect,      :type => Fixnum
  property :is_new,           :type => Fixnum
  property :random,           :type => Float
  property :touched,          :type => String
  property :latest,           :type => Fixnum
  property :length,           :type => Fixnum
  property :no_title_convert, :type => Fixnum


  def self.create_from_dump(obj)
    # TODO: I wonder if there is a way to compine these calls
    page = {}

    # order of this array is important, it corresponds to the data in obj
    attrs = [:page_id, :namespace, :title, :restrictions, :counter, :is_redirect,
             :is_new, :random, :touched, :latest, :length, :no_title_convert]

    attrs.each_index { |i| page[attrs[i]] = obj[i] }
    page = Pages.create(page)
    return page
  end
end
```

Comment: Didn't use neo4j, but after `from.links << to` you do `from.save`. Can it be that there also (or instead) should be `to.save`?

Comment: I'm pretty familiar with Neo4j and I'm stumped. It looks like the relationships are initialized in memory but not persisted to disk. Check if the return value of `#save` is `true` and check if `#persisted?` on each relationship is `true`.

Comment: @IgorS. I tried with to.save and the results were the same.

Comment: @davogones `#persisted?` is false. What should I to to make the relationship persist?

Comment: That's what is puzzling. Perhaps there was a validation error?

Comment: Is the neo4j server running properly? Are you able to manually (through cypher, web admin interface or something) add anything to it?

Comment: @Cort3z I'm not running a separate Neo4j server, [this](http://geekmonkey.org/articles/25-using-neo4j-with-rails-3-2) is the tutorial I used to setup the project. Nodes are persisting, so I think Neo4j is set up correctly.

Comment: @davogones `#errors.any?` returned false, so I don't think there are any validation errors.

Comment: Rake tasks *can* be weird. Can you execute that code from a rails console and have the data persist? (I suggest trying it with a small set first and be sure to mimic what happens in the task as closely as possible)

Comment: @CMW: I just took your advice. I ran the code from the rake task in the rails console, then counted the number of links and it was in the 2000's. I quit the console with `crtl-c` then started a new console. The link count was 0. Then I added the last page to the first page's links object, quit, and restarted. That link persisted, so it looks like there is bug in my code.

Comment: @CMW Even weirder: I ran the script to parse the links, then manually added a link while in the same console session. I had predicted that the manually created link would persist, but when I restarted the console there were no links. Something about the parsing code prevents any links from being saved.

Answer (score 0):

I must admit that I have no idea of how Neo4j works.

Transferring from other databases though, I too assume that either some validation is wrong, or maybe even something is misconfigured in your use of the database. The latter I can't give any advice on where to look, but if it's about validation, you can look at `Page#errors` or try calling `Page#save!` and see what it raises.

One crazy idea that just came to mind looking at [this example](https://github.com/saterus/gritter/blob/master/app/models/grit.rb#L7L8) is that maybe for that relation to be configured properly, you need a back reference, too.

Maybe `has_n(:links).to(Page, :links)` will help you. Or, if that doesn't work:

```
has_n(:links_left).to(Page, :links_right)
has_n(:links_right).from(Page, :links_left)
```

The more I look at this, the more I think the back reference to the same table is not configured properly and thus won't validate.

Comment: I checked both `Page#errors` and `Page#save!`, no errors, nothing raised. I'm looking into back links now.

Comment: I added a back reference but the links still don't save.

Comment: Huh. Then I'm fresh out of ideas.

Comment: Thanks for helping out, I'm looking at example projects to see if they are configured differently, I'm going to award you the bounty for helping out so much.